# sudo apt-get install zip - error

Tags: vps, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install a library zip.
How to fix it? Thank you for your help.
How to fix it? Thank you for your help.
However receives this error:

```
    root@vps300197:~# sudo apt-get install zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zip is already the newest version (3.0-11).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                                                                                                                              See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.                                                                                                                                                             0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-extras (>                                                                                                                                                             = 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.                                                                                                                                                             10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-                                                                                                                                                             extras (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing packagNo apport report written because the error message                                                                                                                                                              indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                       e nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As a root user, you don't need `sudo` before any command you want to run.
2. Normally, you should not use the root account to work on your server, it is very dangerous.
3. If you want install library zip, you should use `apt-get install libzip`, not
   `apt-get install zip`. Zip is already the newest version (3.0-11) on you system.
4. According to the system output information, it seems to be there's some problems with you nginx installation.
5. Try `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo apt-get remove nginx* && sudo apt-get install nginx-full`